# Section definition in Atlassian RefApp?

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to insert a web-item into top level menu section.

```
    <web-item key="googleLink" section="system.top.navigation.bar" weight="40">
        <label key="GOOGLE" />
        <link linkId="GoogleId">http://google.com</link>
    </web-item>
```

where is this section defined: `system.top.navigation.bar`? So I know which sections I can use in system?

Answer (score 0):

I think the page on [Web Fragments](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/web-fragments.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use `section="index.links"`
or try for different location: `section="system.admin/general"`,`section="header.links"` or `section="footer.links"`.